# How to change #define value from another file

Tags: c, embedded, c-preprocessor

I have a source and header file:

```
//boot.h

#define BOOT_DATA_ADDRESS EMBEDDED_ADDRESS

void BootDataReadTable(bootData_t * bootData);
```

```
//boot.c

void BootDataReadTable(bootData_t * bootData)
{
    uint32_t *userPageBootDataTable = (uint32_t *) (BOOT_DATA_ADDRESS );
    uint32_t copiedDataTable[BOOT_DATA_WORDS] = {0U};
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < BOOT_DATA_WORDS; i++)
    {
        copiedDataTable[i] = userPageBootDataTable[i];
    }
    unpackBootData(copiedDataTable, bootData);
}
```

and a test file:

```
//test_boot.c

#include "bootdata.h"

#ifdef BOOT_DATA_ADDRESS
#undef BOOT_DATA_ADDRESS
#define BOOT_DATA_ADDRESS (stackpointer)
#endif 

static uint32_t stack[0x2000] = {0};
static uint32_t * stackpointer = &stack[0];

void test_BootDataReadTable(void)
{
    bootData_t lBootData = {0};

    BootDataReadTable(&lBootData, (uint32_t *)addr);

    //test lBootData
}
```

This code runs on an embedded platform. The memory access in `BootDataReadTable` accesses internal flash on the MCU. For unit testing purposes, I want to run this on my host machine. In `test_boot.c` I want to change the `BOOT_DATA_ADDRESS` to point to my stack area on my host machine so that `BootDataReadTable` just accesses some dummy data instead of trying to access internal flash.

I'm compiling/running the unit test with `ceedling`.

The method I'm using above does not work. What am I doing wrong/how can I accomplish changing the value of `BOOT_DATA_ADDRESS` from another file?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What do you expect it to do? (And if you expect it to reach into a separate compilation which might well have already been done and somehow recompile it, what mechanism do you think might be used to accomplish your goal?)

Comment: The pre-processor stuff looks OK - however, defining `BOOT_DATA_ADDRESS` as `(*stackpointer)` looks a bit odd. Are you sure you want the de-reference in there? (Maybe just `(stackpointer)`??)

Comment: @Adrian Mole the dereference was a typo.

Comment: @rici I edited the post hopefully this clears up your question

Comment: So, suppose you've compiled `boot.c`: `gcc -c -o boot.o boot.c`. Now you compile `test_boot.c`: `gcc -c -o test_boot.o test_boot.c`. How do you expect the second command to alter `boot.o`? Or, if you did it in another order, to remember that it will have to change `boot.o` when you eventually get around to compiling it? Preprocessor macros are used to preprocess the source; once it's compiled, they have been fully used up.

Comment: @rici Yup that makes sense. Is there no way to change compilation or linking order or something to accomplish this?

Comment: @peter: if you're prepared to recompile the entire project, it is obviously doable. Otherwise, no. Separate compilation is separate compilation.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're doing this for unit testing, I assume you have no problem compiling specifically for unit tests (probably not even for the target architecture).

`env.h`:

```
#ifdef UNIT_TESTING

extern int stack[0x2000];
#define BOOT_DATA_ADDRESS (stack)

#endif
```

`boot.h`:

```
#include "env.h"

#ifndef BOOT_DATA_ADDRESS
#define BOOT_DATA_ADDRESS ((void *)0xdeadbeef)
#endif

void BootDataReadTable(void);
```

`boot.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "boot.h"

void BootDataReadTable(void)
{
    printf("BOOT_DATA_ADDRESS = %p\n", BOOT_DATA_ADDRESS);
}
```

`main.c`:

```
#include "boot.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    BootDataReadTable();
}
```

`test_boot.c`:

```
#include "boot.h"

int stack[0x2000] = {0};

void test_BootDataReadTable(void)
{
    BootDataReadTable();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    test_BootDataReadTable();
}
```

`Makefile`:

```
demo: main test_boot
    ./main
    ./test_boot

main::
    cc -o main main.c boot.c

test_boot::
    cc -DUNIT_TESTING -o test_boot test_boot.c boot.c
```

output:

```
cc -o main main.c boot.c
cc -DUNIT_TESTING -o test_boot test_boot.c boot.c
./main
BOOT_DATA_ADDRESS = 0xdeadbeef
./test_boot
BOOT_DATA_ADDRESS = 0x601060
```